# How to set a unique ID for very button in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

```html
 
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="modal-body clscard" >
        <div th:if="${session.listSize}!=0"> 
         <div class="card removeit mb-2 asp1 bdrtwenty" th:each="task,itrIndex : ${session.taskList}">
            
            <div class="card-header text-center">
                <span class="fntsizes"> Activity Reminder : </span><span class="fntsizes" th:text="${task.taskName}"></span> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-body" id="datas">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                   <p class="text-center"><b>Description</b></p>
                   <p class="dsctask text-center" th:text ="${task.taskDescription}"> </p>   
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="row justify-content-center">
                       <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                           <span class="text-center" for="data"><b>Target Date :</b></span> 
                           <span class="text-center" th:text= "${task.taskTresholdCutOff}"></span>
                       </div>
                       
                   </div>
                   
                   <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto mt-2">
                   <div class="form-group">
   
    <textarea class="form-control" id="userdata" rows="6"></textarea>
  </div>
                   </div>
                   </div>
            

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer" style="padding:5px;">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"> <button th:attr="onclick=|saveIt('${task.taskId}')|" class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent">Done</button></div>
             <div class="col-md-3"><button th:id="'btnSubmit'+${itrIndex.index}" class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent" disabled="disabled">Skip</button></div>
                
            </div>
               
            </div>
            
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#userdata").keyup(function () {
            var btnSubmit = $("#btnSubmit");
            //var btnSubmit = $('btnSubmit').each((btn, index) => {btn.attr('id', `btnSubmit${index}`});
            if ($(this).val().trim() != "") {
                btnSubmit.removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
                btnSubmit.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

```html
 <div class="modal-body clscard" >
        <div th:if="${session.listSize}!=0"> 
         <div class="card removeit mb-2 asp1 bdrtwenty" th:each="task,itrIndex : ${session.taskList}">
            
            <div class="card-header text-center">
                <span class="fntsizes"> Activity Reminder : </span><span class="fntsizes" th:text="${task.taskName}"></span> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-body" id="datas">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                   <p class="text-center"><b>Description</b></p>
                   <p class="dsctask text-center" th:text ="${task.taskDescription}"> </p>   
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="row justify-content-center">
                       <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                           <span class="text-center" for="data"><b>Target Date :</b></span> 
                           <span class="text-center" th:text= "${task.taskTresholdCutOff}"></span>
                       </div>
                       
                   </div>
                   
                   <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto mt-2">
                   <div class="form-group">
   
    <textarea class="form-control" id="userdata" rows="6"></textarea>
  </div>
                   </div>
                   </div>
            

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer" style="padding:5px;">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"> <button th:attr="onclick=|saveIt('${task.taskId}')|" class="btn btn-primary float-right clscurrent">Done</button></div>
             <div class="col-md-3"><button th:id="'btnSubmit'+${itrIndex.index}" class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent" disabled="disabled">Skip</button></div>
                
            </div>
               
            </div>
```

actually I'm facing issue with buttons id's basically i am getting dynamic id's (like btnSubmit0, btnSubmit1)for buttons here I just to to when i enter a text in textarea button should enable otherwise it should be in disabled. but in my script i have a static id like butSubmit how to resolve this issue , Is there any possible pls help me on it.

note:actually i am using bootstrap card in that card I have button and other hand this card have a loop also , I' mean every button inside the loop due to i have append a unique id to buttons.

Comment: Does each *task* have an `id`?

Comment: Something like ```$('button').each((btn, index) => {btn.attr('id', `btnSubmit${index}`});``` maybe?

Comment: @Amit I have button like this <button th:id="'btnSubmit'+${itrIndex.index}" class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent" disabled="disabled">Skip</button>

Answer (score 0):

You have to update ID in html like,

> id="btnSubmit"+ i

```
<button id="btnSubmit"+ i  class="btn btn-danger float-right clscurrent" disabled="disabled">Skip</button>
```

script on load/ready

```
var i=0;
$('.btn').each(function(){
  i++;
  var newID='btnSubmit'+i;
  $(this).attr('id',newID);
});
```

Comment: hi @Amit I'm already getting id's dynamically by thymeleaf but in my script how to handle that